# Swift 4: Add pencil to sign PDF file

Tags: swift, pdfkit

I try to add a pencil functionality to my NavigationController to add a customer sign in PDF file. At the moment, I'm able to create and show my own PDF file but not to sign it in my App.

In the files App, the pencil is shown at the right top corner. After selecting the pencil, I can sign the PDF file.

[image]

How can I achieve this for my own App?

Comment: Did you find a solution, yet? :)

Comment: nope... sorry, I could not find anything.

Comment: @Tobonaut I solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the help of this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@artempoluektov/ios-pdfkit-ink-annotations-tutorial-4ba19b474dce).

The complete source code is available at [this](https://bitbucket.org/poluektov/pdfkit-demo/src/master/) repo.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you have a controller A which has an embed in navigation Controller If you want to add an image to the top bar you can first uncheck the Show navigation bar in the navigation controller properties from storyboard then you can add custom buttons and set any image you want

Comment: Did you read my question? My aim is not to add an image to my navigation Controller, but I would like to add the pencil functionality instead.